# Does unix SCP return an error code for network issues

Tags: unix, scp

In a script, I am using SCP to copy huge file to another host.

scp -qrp hugefile.txt /opt/perf05/tmp

However, we have noticed that this file is not being copied. I am suspecting this was because we are losing connection while copying this huge file across network. Does scp command return any error code in case of such network disconnect or is there any other way of debugging this to find out what exactly causes this failed copy. Thanks in advance.

-Steve

Comment: It seems to return $?=1 for me if the connection is broken during the transfer. What does it return for you? Test and see!

Answer (score 1):

```
scp -v
```

gives debugging information.

scp does return non-zero (>1) when the connection fails or any other network error occurs.

Comment: Thanks. The issue was with source file not being able to be found. I enabled verbose mode and debugged the issue.